# How to consume ModelAndView Response from spring MVC in Angular 6?

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a project where I have to consume the response returned by spring MVC controller ( return type of controller is `ModelAndView`) and show that as UI.
I know how to consume JSON response in Angular but I don't know how to deal in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `$http` it means you are making a Ajax call.

You don't get a **ModelAndView** object in AJAX, since it just sees the response from the request and what it will see is HTML.

If you want to get just the data **don't use ModelAndView**, I suggest you make another controller method just returning the object you want with a `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: so that means there is no way we can consume modelAndView right?

Comment: No. Only if you consume the entire html text and parse it somehow.

Comment: parsing html text will be lot to do ,i'll go with restController. thanks